# Unexpected results when trying to print a random variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm teaching myself python (from http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ using python 3.3.2, rewriting the activities as needed). I was just trying the random module, and it gave me
(`<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x00000000024D1798>>`)
as a result from:

```
import random

print (random.randint(0, 10))
```

At this point I'm mostly learning just from experimentation, with a bit of help from tutorials at times. I have googled for this, and I've searched Stack Overflow but nothing has come up.

Comment: After looking at it for a bit, turns out I probably forgot to save it when I added the .randint bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the code you ran; you did this instead:

```
>>> import random
>>> print(random.randint)
<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x7fdadc0fbc20>>
```

Note that the `randint` function is not being called.

What you are seeing is the string representation of a method object.

Your code otherwise is perfectly correct, it is just not the code that ran when you saw that error:

```
>>> print(random.randint(0, 10))
7
```

Comment: From that I suspect that you think that I am running python directly from the CLI. I'm using NP++ to write script, and Powershell to run the script

Comment: @user2512440: I am merely demonstrating what happened. The same thing happens running the script in Powershell. Using the Python interpreter prompt makes it easier to show exactly what returns what.

Comment: Thanks then, I don't quite understand what's happening though. If I wanted the script to return a integer in the ranges 0 to 10, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: @Mmmmyum: The code you posted in your question is correct; but it is *not the code that causes the error*.

Comment: Oh wait, now I understand what you mean. It just took awhile for me to understand what you meant by string representation. (I started python on Friday, so it'll take awhile.)